# dc.js - unable to plot line chart on average

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I'm creating a line chart using `dc.js`.

Link for the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/55ZW5/).

Challenge I'm facing is. I'm trying to plot a line graph on average of values which is not happening currently.

In the fiddle I have two javascript variables namely - `dateHits` and `dateDimTotal`.

`dateHits` is produced using `reduceSum` and `dateDimTotal` is the average on date.

If I group the line chart using `dateHits`. Line chart appears without any problem.

But if I replace the dateHits to `dateDimTotal` nothing appears.

Someone help me in where I'm doing the wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/VividD/pBhC8/) will display average values by date.

Plot of averages:

[image]

(it looks almost the same as original plot from your jsfiddle, but y axis values are different)

I'll add some comments on code shortly.

EDIT: Comments:

You were almost done, but needed a couple of peaces of code for the whole app to work.

I rewrote reduceXXX() functions in the following way:

```
function reduceAdd(p, v) {
        ++p.count;
        p.total += v.value;
        if (p.count == 0) {
            p.average = 0;
        } else {
            p.average = p.total / p.count;
        };
        return p;
    }

    function reduceRemove(p, v) {
        --p.count;
        p.total -= v.value;
        if (p.count == 0) {
            p.average = 0;
        } else {
            p.average = p.total / p.count;
        };
        return p;
    }

    function reduceInitial() {
        return {
            count: 0,
            total: 0,
            average: 0
        };
}
```

So, there is a field `average` that will be always maintained with correct value. I think such code organization is cleaner, though there may be some alternatives.

I added accessor function too (so that dc.js know what to display):

```
    .valueAccessor(function(p) { return p.value.average; })
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have additional question, or need clarification.

Comment: Yea! I missed the `.valueAccessor`. I figured that out long back. But forgot to post it over here. Anyways thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: Can you let me know how can I start the `y-axis` from 50 or 100 instead of 0?

Comment: Ask a separate question.

Comment: [**Link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21597790/dc-js-queries-related-to-axis). Please help.

Comment: Vividd - Can you please let me know how can take the `min` value of the average you've calculated. Tried using `d3.min(function(p) { return p.value.average; })` but didn't get. Please help.