# dc.js - queries related to axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I have some queries with the `axis` in dc.js.

I'm using line and row chart.

How can i arrange the row chart labels in a different order?

And how can I set the `y-axis` of a line chart to start to 20 or 30 or 50 instead of 0.

Can some help me in this?

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/VividD/pBhC8/) I wanted to make the y axis to start from 200 in the line chart.

And also help me in how to arrange the row chart in order of a week. i.e., monday, tuesday and so on.

Comment: Please post link to your fiddle so that it is easier for people to answer.

Comment: VividD - Please help. Stuck in this for two days.

Comment: Sorry, I work on my project at work and don't have enough time for this. This could be pretty complicated question. You should be also more specific. Do you expect "200" to be hardcoded or dependent on data? Or similar questions. If you are not clear, people will be reluctant to answer, since after they answer, you'll probably say: "Hey, but now this doesn't work..." and so on to infinity. Also, try different examples on d3js.org, and try searching here for similar questions. If you explain what you've tried, and what the problems were, it would be more likely for somebody to answer...

Comment: I found it. I was so stupid that `d3.scale.linear` didn't flash. Finally did it using `.(d3.scale.linear().domain([50, 500]))`.

Comment: Cool! Enter this as an answer (you are allowed to answer your own questions)! It may be useful for other people.

Comment: Please look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21571573/dc-js-unable-to-plot-line-chart-on-average). I've commented a thing. Please reply for it.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. I was so stupid that `d3.scale.linear` didn't flash. Finally did it using `.(d3.scale.linear().domain([50, 500]))`